# WCM REST API Query

Tags: wcm

I need to use REST API to query IBM WCM 8.0 on the contents stored in it.
When i use the following query format, it works fine:

```
wcmrest/query?keyword=ABC&keyword=DEF
```

This returns all the contents which has both ABC and DEF as values in keywords.

My requirement is to search contents that matches either ABC or DEF keywords.
Kindly let me know what query I need use for the same?

Also, is it possible to search WCM based on user defined metadata?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic/adhoc queries do not have a query parameter that can perform an OR for multiple keywords.

This can be achieved using the a pre-defined query: http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD004/wcm/wcm_rest_defined.html

For example you could use the following user defined query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definedQuery pageSize="10" page="1" restrictParameters="false" depth="DESCENDANTS">
    <select>
        <keywordIn>
            <keyword>ABC</keyword>
            <keyword>XYZ</keyword>
        </keywordIn>
    </select>
    <allowParameters/>
</definedQuery>
```